# Android ListView does not update onResume

Tags: android, listview, onresume

I made an Activity for searching people that also shows history of recent research.

If I long click on an item of the history it asks me if I want to delete it. If I press "Yes" it deletes the list item.

So, I write something and click to "Search" button. This brings me in another Activity with results. Here I click on result so it stores the person info and brings me in the person page.

When I come back I don't see the new person in the history.

So I overwritten onResume() but it still not work and now I cannot delete items from the history list.

Here the code:

```
package com.lpsmt.proffinder;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.lpsmt.R;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity
{
    protected Db db = null;
    protected List<ProfBean> historyProfs = null;
    protected ProfListItemAdapter listAdapter = null;
    protected ListView listView = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.db = new Db(this);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.prof_finder_home);

        this.historyProfs = this.db.getHistory(-1); // -1 means with no limits
        this.listAdapter = new ProfListItemAdapter(HomeActivity.this, R.id.prof_finder_history_list_view, this.historyProfs);

        this.listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.prof_finder_history_list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(this.listAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfPageActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("profId", HomeActivity.this.historyProfs.get(position).getProfId());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                HomeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id)
            {
                Resources resources = HomeActivity.this.getResources();
                String title = resources.getString(R.string.prof_finder_history_delete_title);
                String message = resources.getString(R.string.prof_finder_history_delete_message);
                AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle(title);
                adb.setMessage(message);

                final int positionToRemove = position;
                String positive = resources.getString(R.string.prof_finder_history_delete_positive);
                String negative = resources.getString(R.string.prof_finder_history_delete_negative);
                adb.setNegativeButton(negative, null);
                adb.setPositiveButton(positive, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ProfBean prof = HomeActivity.this.historyProfs.get(positionToRemove);
                        HomeActivity.this.db.deleteProf(prof.getProfId());

                        HomeActivity.this.historyProfs.remove(positionToRemove);
                        HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                HomeActivity.this.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }});
                adb.show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void searchProf(View view) throws Exception
    {
        EditText queryEditText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.prof_finder_search_query);
        String query = queryEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        queryEditText.setText(query);

        if (query.length() < 3) {
            String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.prof_finder_query_too_short);
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SearchResultActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("query", query);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        this.historyProfs = this.db.getHistory(-1);
        this.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set any new data to list view. Thats why your new contact isn't added to the list after `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You need to add some method into adapter like

```
setData(List<ProfBean> data)
{
this.currentAdaptersList= data;
}
```

and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. So the final onResume will be :

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    this.historyProfs = this.db.getHistory(-1);
    this.listAdapter.setData(this.historyProfs);
    this.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Enjoy.

And using onResume() for this task is bad idea. Is better to use onActivityResult.

Comment: This is how implemented my adapter: http://pastebin.com/xyPREkL8 . I use the internal storage system to insert and retrieve items. When I change the ArrayList it changes in the adapter too. I'm gonna try with onActivityResult().

Comment: Before trying onActivityResult(), just try to reinit your listview instead of callinig notify.

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged() didn't work for me either. I was able to solve this a little bit differently:

1. I use OnStart() (in a derived class from Fragment)
2. I use setNotifyOnChange() of the ArrayAdapter:

`ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.logListView);
 listView.setAdapter(logAdapter);
 logAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);`

I create the adapter once:

logAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, activity.logMessages);

in onViewCreated().